# Run a remote bash command through ssh

Tags: bash, perl, ubuntu, ssh

I have the following script that I plan to use to execute a bash command on a remote server. Every time this script runs it should check whether the remote MySQL (PXC) server is undergoing SST.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $time = localtime();

my $file = '/db-common-list/names.txt';
open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";

while ( my $hostname = <$info> )  {

    my $wsrep_check = `ssh $hostname ps -ef |grep mysql | grep wsrep_sst_xtrabackup-v2`;

    if ( index($wsrep_check, 'State transfer in progress, setting sleep higher mysqld') != -1 ) {
        print "$time: Server $hostname";
        last if $. == 2;
    }
}

close $info;
```

Inside `/db-common-list/names.txt` is a list of databases that the script should loop through line by line. So it looks something like this:

```
db-test-1
db-test-2
db-test-3
db-test-4
...
```

But when I run the script, the command line just hangs and never displays anything, at which point I have to manually force the script to stop executing. So after several minutes with nothing but the script just hanging in the terminal, I use Ctrl-D to stop the script and I get this:

```
thegeorgia@cron-db$ ./test.cron
Connection to db-test-1 closed.
Connection to db-test-2 closed.
thegeorgia@cron-db$ ./test.cron
```

I can ssh and ping these remote as demonstrated below servers so thats not the issue for sure:

```
thegeorgis@cron-db$ ping db-test-1
PING db-test-1 (10.1.4.205) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from db-test-1 (10.1.4.205): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.263 ms
64 bytes from db-test-1 (10.1.4.205): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.222 ms
```

All servers involved are running Ubuntu.

NOTE:
As suggested by Borodin, i added the chomp as follows:

```
    while( my $hostname = <$info>)  {
    my $server = chomp( $hostname );
    my $wsrep_check = `ssh $server ls`;
         if ( index($wsrep_check, 'State transfer in progress, setting sleep higher mysqld') != -1 ){
            print "$time: Server $server";
       }
last if $. == 2;
}
```

And when i run the perl script, i now get the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host 1 port 22: Invalid argument
ssh: connect to host 1 port 22: Invalid argument
```

SOLUTION:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my $time = localtime();
my $file = '/db-common-list/names.txt';
open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";

while( my $hostname = <$info>)  {
    chomp( $hostname );
    my $wsrep_check = `ssh $hostname ps -ef |grep mysql | grep wsrep_sst_xtrabackup-v2`;
         if ( $wsrep_check ne "" ){
            print "$time: Server $hostname\n";
       }
}
close $info;
```

Comment: Are you having this issue only when running the script remotely? What happens when you run the `ps -ef` locally on that server?

Comment: 1) One thing that can hang here is the `ssh`.  Can you just ssh to that server from a Perl script and get anything back?   Did you try to print anything out of the `while` loop, after running `ssh`? For instance, the `$wsrep_check` variable? (2) Is this your complete script? Can there be more, that hangs after `while` completes?

Comment: The script runs on locally. The issue seems to be with ssh part.

Comment: Can you try to add `print "$wsrep_check\n";` before the `if` statement and tell us what happens?

Comment: What other things does your script do?  The code that is shown never deals with a database so there'd be no reason to get `Connection ..closed`, as far as this code is concerned.

Comment: @dzim it just hangs again. But if i remove the `ssh...` statement, i can test printing just fine. So the issue is with the way the ssh works i am guessing. And no, the code does not need to deal with a DB. Just need to know how to execute a bash command on a remote server from a perl script.

Comment: OK, thanks -- it appears that @Borodin figured it out.  You surely need to `chomp` that (and in my quick test `ssh` does hang with a newline following the hostname).

Comment: Why are you assigning the chomped hostname to another scalar? just do `chomp ($hostname);`

Comment: @TheGeorgia change the last part you edited to this: `while( my $hostname = <$info>)  {
   chomp( $hostname );
    my $wsrep_check = \`ssh $hostname ls\`;
         if ( index($wsrep_check, 'State transfer in progress, setting sleep higher mysqld') != -1 ){
            print "$time: Server $hostname";
       }
last if $. == 2;
}`

Comment: You are right Barnard. My bad. Have edited on my script already.

Comment: Ok so now your ssh should work.

Comment: Thanks guys for all the help. Its working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to

```
chomp $hostname;
```

before your ssh command to remove the trailing newline from the read

I also suspect that your `last if $. == 2` should be *outside* the `if` block

Perl has built-in support for regular expressions, so there is rarely any need for a call to `index`

```
if ( index($wsrep_check, 'State transfer in progress, setting sleep higher mysqld') != -1 ) { ... }
```

would usually be written

```
if ( $wsrep_check =~ /State transfer in progress, setting sleep higher mysqld/ ) { ... }
```

but what you have written is fine

Comment: with your suggestions, it does not hang, but throws an error: /home/thegeorgia/.bashrc: line 2: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: @TheGeorgia: That is a problem with your `.bashrc`. You need to find where `virtualenvwrapper.sh` is on the relevant host and correct the path.

Comment: Check my original post to see changes and current output please

Comment: you mean add on the local server, or remote servers?

Comment: chomp did the trick. Thanks @Borodin and everybody that provided feedback

Comment: I have posted the revised version now